# Minimum insert for stem: line or arrow

Tags: road-bike, stem

I would like to raise my handlebar and have come across the following markings on my stem. [image]
Can I raise this stem only until the upper arrow disappears or does "Min Insert" refer to the line below and I can raise it 2-3cm more?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that line is part of a logo, and not a marking for insertion.

Comment: You can see the logo more clearly in [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/172229040050) ebay listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow is the min insertion mark.

Comment: How do we know? Can you explain? The arrow is quite high on the stem, giving almost no room for adjustment.

Comment: It's right next to the words "MIN INSERT," and the line is part of the Kalloy logo, and normal stems don't really ever have any such markings above the height line.

Comment: Thank you for for feedback. I think the line being part of a logo and the stem being typically free of markings above the min insert are really good arguments.